# org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"xmldata":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"}

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, hive

I am trying to load data which is in xml format, into a hive table:-

My XML file looks like this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
<book>
  <id>11</id>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44</price>
</book>
<book>
  <id>44</id>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5</price>
</book>
</catalog>
```

Firstly I have loaded the xml data into a managed table and then I am using the xpath UDF function to parse the XML data and load actual values in my main table.Following are hive queries I am trying with:-

```
create table XmlSample(xmlData string);


load data inpath 'EmployeeDetails.xml' into table XmlSample;

create table xpath_table(id int,genre string,price string);

Insert overwrite table xpath_table select xpath_int(xmlData, '/catalog/book/id/text()'), xpath_string(xmlData, '/catalog/book/genre/text()'), xpath_string(xmlData, '/catalog/book/price/text()') from XmlSample;
```

But I am getting exception-

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"xmldata":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"xmldata":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:544)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:157)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public int org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.xml.UDFXPathInteger.evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)  on object org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.xml.UDFXPathInteger@37fd3f of class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.xml.UDFXPathInteger with arguments {<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>:java.lang.String, /catalog/book/id/text():java.lang.String} of size 2
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:1030)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFBridge.evaluate(GenericUDFBridge.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:504)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:842)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:504)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:842)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:534)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:1006)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid expression '/catalog/book/id/text()'
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.xml.UDFXPathUtil.eval(UDFXPathUtil.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.xml.UDFXPathUtil.evalNumber(UDFXPathUtil.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.xml.UDFXPathInteger.evaluate(UDFXPathInteger.java:35)
```

Can someone please advise how can I avoid these exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**1. Brings each record to one line (deletes the `catalog` tags):**

`cat EmployeeDetails.xml | tr -d '&' | tr '\n' ' ' | tr '\r' ' ' | sed 's|</book>|</book>\n|g' | sed 's/<catalog>//g' | grep -v '^\s*$'  | sed '3d' > EmployeeDetails1.xml`

**2. Create a directory and copy the converted xml file into HDFS:**

`hadoop fs -mkdir /usr/xml/`

`hadoop fs -put EmployeeDetails1.xml /usr/xml/EmployeeDetails.xml`

**3. Create table to load xml in hive:**

`create table XmlSample(xmldata string);`

**4. Load xml file in HDFS into hive xml table:**

`load data inpath '/usr/xml/EmployeeDetails.xml' into table XmlSample;`

**5. Create a table to extract data from xml table in hive:**

`create table xpath_table(id int,genre string,price string);`

**6. Insert extracted data from xml table to your table in hive:**

`insert overwrite table xpath_table select xpath_int(xmldata,'book/id'), xpath_string(xmldata,'book/genre'), xpath_string(xmldata,'book/price') from XmlSample;`

> **Note:** I have just added **step 1** and modified your **step 6** format. These
>   steps worked for me. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rajesh! It works for me.However I still wonder why do we need to remove the root tag and bring everything in one line.Can't we load it directly in hive table before any processing.Generally every xml file has some root element, so do we always need to remove it?

Comment: NIce to hear it works :). This hive command needs a `same start and end tag` for each line like `book` tags. Since you have `only one root tag` for the whole document, you cant use my hive command. If you dont want to remove root tag, then you have to modify `step 1`(to add root start and end tags on each line)  and `step 6` (add catalog before book like this `catalog/book/id`). Good Luck :)

Comment: That helps! :-) Is that a kind of a limitation we have in dealing with xml data in hadoop, that we must first process XML file in such a way that each line starts and ends with same tag.Can't we simply load a xml file into hive table without doing any processing at all?

Comment: I tried to process xml file without any filters, but all in vain. So i switched to this method and it works good till now.